# Añadir valor a Page<Proyecto>

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente variable:

```
Page<Proyecto> proyectos = null;
```

y no consigo añadir un nuevo proyecto a esta página de proyectos.

He intentado:

```
proyectos.getContent().add(new Proyecto())
```

Entre otras muchas cosas pero no funciona, obtengo el error:

An exception occurred: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias

Comment: La clase Page es de algún paquete externo?

Comment: Como dice Andres, vendría muy bien saber que es Page exactamente... de todas formas te puedo adelantar que mientras proyectos sea null no vas a poder hacer nada con él... necesitarás algún constructor

Comment: ¿Es el `Page` de Spring Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO:

proyectos.getContent() devuelve una lista estática, no se puede modificar. La solución pasa por crear una lista de proyectos auxiliar, ir rellenándola en bucle, y finalmente crear nueva instancia de la página.

```
    List<Proyecto> list = new LinkedList<Proyecto>();
    
    for (int k = 0; k < nombreFaseActual.size(); k++) {
        
        list.addAll(servicioProyectos.findAll(...);
            
    }
    proyectos = new PageImpl<>(list);
```